# Is there a way to extend the time for a Selenium Docker container to finish in GitLab?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab, containers, gitlab-ci-runner

To replicate this scenario on your own local machine, use this tutorial: https://github.com/alexandremariano4/template-gitlab-test/blob/main/README.md

I'm using the following repository on GitLab (which you can copy and test on your machine) to run the tests: https://github.com/alexandremariano4/template-gitlab-test

I need to be able to increase the time that the container is finished inside the pipeline, in my current context, I have the following gitlab-ci.yml file

Here is a gitlab-ci.yml file: https://gist.github.com/alexandremariano4/ae1789074046e7f386a99b15090cff8e

The only thing that my code "teste.py" does is enter google and print the page title name, just using it for tests.
Although my scenario is working correctly, and in fact this pipeline is recording the video as it should in the "videos" folder, the selenium/video container is ending abruptly, not giving time for the functionality to create the complete file to have success.

As you can see inside this docker-compose.yml container, when I use the "docker compose down" command, the container executes some process:
[Image of process running in docker-compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm9B6.png)

[Image of the container running on gitlab at the moment it is finalizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq8LH.png)
These two images, I took at the exact moment when, respectively, I used the "docker compose down" command and the moment when the container is starting to be closed in gitlab

I tried to change time-out parameters inside the runner using the shutdown_timeout parameter, but it didn't work, I saw something related to SIGTERM and SIGKILL, which seems to be something related to the time it takes for the container to be canceled, however, I don't I couldn't see any way to change this, or apply what I saw on the gitlab forums to my context.

I need to be able to postpone closing the selenium/video container, so that it can do all the steps that are performed by the ffmpeg library, video compression, etc (I don't know exactly what it does).
So the evidence that is generated is not a broken mp4 file.

[Gitlab artifact image with broken mp4 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcPWA.png)

Comment: Ok,you must explain what your problem is. Execuiton time of E2E tests?

Comment: I need to increase time closure of container selenium/video, for it to finish the processes, 
take a look at the images I've uploaded, they explain well that locally, the container closes naturally, but in gitlab, it's closing abruptly.

Comment: are u using self-hosted Gitlab runners? read https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27223

Answer (score 0):

I have no know-how with CI, but I can try to help. Have you  tried  starting to record video using these settings?

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y wget
  - wget http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.14/selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
  - java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub &
  - java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - start-video-recording.sh # Start video recording
    - # Your code to perform tests using Selenium
    - stop-video-recording.sh # Stop video recording
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /path/to/video/directory/*.mp4
```

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST http://localhost:4444/grid/admin/VideoRecordingControlServlet?action=start&sessionName=$CI_JOB_ID
```

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -X POST http://localhost:4444/grid/admin/VideoRecordingControlServlet?action=stop&sessionName=$CI_JOB_ID
```

Is it makes sense for you?